# noob SQLite Cursor error on android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

Ï developed a little SQLite database to add a list of goods, when I fletchallgoods through the database I have an error that says the index is not valid:

the code that generate the error:

```
...
Cursor goodsCursor = goodsfletcher.fetchAllGoods();
String goods[] = new String[goodsCursor.getCount()] ;
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.baskettable);
for(int i=0;i<=goods.length;i++){
    String Goodname = goodsCursor.getString(1).toString() ;
...
```

the clss Dbadapter that handle the conexion:

```
public Cursor fetchAllGoods() {

        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_CODART, KEY_ARTI,
                KEY_PROV, KEY_PRECBOL, KEY_QUANT}, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

The log cat of the error:

```
03-14 16:19:37.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5690): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 16:19:37.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5690): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.remotedata.firstapp/com.remotedata.firstapp.chartView}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
03-14 16:19:37.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5690):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
03-14 16:19:37.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5690):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
03-14 16:19:37.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5690):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-14 16:19:37.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5690):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
03-14 16:19:37.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5690):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-14 16:19:37.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5690):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-14 16:19:37.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5690):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
03-14 16:19:37.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5690):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 16:19:37.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5690):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-14 16:19:37.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5690):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
03-14 16:19:37.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5690):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
03-14 16:19:37.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5690):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-14 16:19:37.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5690): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
03-14 16:19:37.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5690):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
03-14 16:19:37.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5690):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
03-14 16:19:37.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5690):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
03-14 16:19:37.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5690):     at com.remotedata.firstapp.chartView.onCreate(chartView.java:36)
03-14 16:19:37.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5690):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-14 16:19:37.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5690):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
03-14 16:19:37.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5690):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: How many columns is the cursor returning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move to the first record in your Cursor before retrieving values.

Ex.

```
Cursor goodsCursor = goodsfletcher.fetchAllGoods();
String goods[] = new String[goodsCursor.getCount()] ;
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.baskettable);
if (c.moveToFirst()){
    do {
        String Goodname = goodsCursor.getString(1).toString() ;
    }while (c.moveToNext());


}

c.close();
```